# Can't access nested object properties in a single object from JSON call in REACT

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm making an Rails API call and return a single JSON object that has a nested User Object and a tag list array. However, I can't access the nested Object.

this.props.post.user.name throws:
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

I am confused because when I make the call to PostsIndex in PostsIndex.js and get an array of objects and map through it I can access everything.

Is there something I need to do when only dealing with a single object?

PostShow.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';



export default class PostShow extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    post: {}
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  const { match: { params } } = this.props;
  axios
    .get(`/api/posts/${params.postId}`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ post: response.data});
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <Post post={this.state.post}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Post extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="centered">
          <small className ="small" >  | Posted by: {this.props.post.user.name}  on   | Tags:  </small>
          <h3>{this.props.post.title}</h3>
          <img className="image " src={this.props.post.image}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className = "songTitle"> {this.props.post.song_title} </p>
          <p className= "postBody"> {this.props.post.body} </p>
          <div className = "link" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.post.link }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what the JSON object looks like from /api/posts/7:

`{"id":7,
"title":"adgaadg",
"body":"adgadgagdgd",
"post_type":"Video",
"tag_list":["ERL"],
"image":"/images/original/missing.png",
"song_title":"adgdgdgd",
"created_at":"2018-08-11T21:57:00.447Z",
"user":{"id":2,"name":"John","bio":"bio","location":"Reno"}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `this.props.post.user` will be `undefined` before your request has finished, and trying to access `name` on that will give rise to your error.

You could e.g. set the initial `post` to `null` and not render anything until your request is complete.

**Example**

```
class PostShow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      match: { params }
    } = this.props;
    axios
      .get(`/api/posts/${params.postId}`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ post: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.state;

    if (post === null) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Post post={post} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`axios.get` is an async operation and `<Post post={this.state.post}/>` renders before `this.setState({ post: response.data});` which means when Post component renders `this.state.post` is empty object. So what you can do is, initialize your post with null in constructor

```
this.state = {
   post: null
};
```

and instead of `<Post post={this.state.post}/>` do `{this.state.post && <Post post={this.state.post}/>}` it will render post only if its exists and not null.