# Cannot access only one object key in React Redux (all other keys are ok)

Tags: react-redux

In a React Redux App I have a component called `ItemDetail` which of course is supposed to render all the details related to the item it retrieves based on the URL parameter `id`.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../../../../../actions'

const ItemDetail = (props) => {
    const mapState = (state) => {
        return {
            currentItem: state.currentItem,
        }
    }

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { currentItem } = useSelector(mapState)



    useEffect(() => {
        let { id } = props.match.params
        dispatch(actions.fetchCurrentItem(id))
        dispatch(actions.setAside(false))
        return () => dispatch(actions.setAside(true))
    }, [dispatch, props.match.params])



    return (

        <div id="item-detail">
            <div id="picture">picture {currentItem.image}</div>
            <div id="details">details {currentItem.name} {currentItem.rating[1]}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

An `Item` object would look like this:

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Dell XPS 13",
      "value": "dell-xps-13",
      "category": 2,
      "department": 2,
      "price": 1599.0,
      "discount": 0,
      "image": "xps13_9370_4_3_01.jpg",
      "rating": {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 0,
        "3": 8,
        "4": 12,
        "5": 21
      },
      "sold": 520,
      "left": 34,
      "features": [
        "10th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-1065G7 Processor",
        "6.8% larger 16:10 display - 13 inches, 17% larger touchpad and an edge-to-edge backlit keyboard with larger key caps",
        "6% thinner design with more power",
        "long battery life —up to 18 hours, 49 minutes* on a Full HD+ model when using when using productivity applications like Word or Excel or up to 11 hours, 51 minutes* when streaming Netflix"
      ]
}
```

Now, I can access every single key but "rating". In fact, when I try to access {currentItem.rating[1]}, I get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`. It looks like if the object is undefined, but if I only try to access {currentItem.rating} without specifying the key value, I get `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` as expected.

So, how comes when I try to access any other value, or simply `rating` the object is found, but when I try to access the object key (in this case '1') the object is undefined?

Thanks for any reply.

EDIT

I have got a feeling that the problem is in my reducer. Just in case, here it is.

```
import * as actions from './../actions'

const initState = {
    loading: false,
    categories: [],
    currentCategory: {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "any",
        "name": "--- Any ---",
        "departments": []
    },
    currentDepartment: {
        "id": 0,
        "value": "any",
        "name": "--- Any ---",
    },
    toggler: 'hidden',
    error: '',
    minimumPrice: 0,
    maximumPrice: 5000,
    items: [],
    valueSearched: '',
    currentItem: {},
    aside: true
}

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.SET_CATEGORY:
            return {
                ...state, currentCategory: action.payload.category, departments: action.payload.departments, currentDepartment: {
                    "id": 0,
                    "value": "any",
                    "name": "--- Any ---",
                }
            }
        case actions.FETCH_CATEGORIES_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, loading: true }
        case actions.FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loading: false, categories: action.payload }
        case actions.FETCH_CATEGORIES_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, loading: false, categories: action.payload }
        case actions.SET_DEPARTMENT:
            return { ...state, currentDepartment: action.payload }
        case actions.TOGGLE:
            return { ...state, toggler: action.payload }
        case actions.ASIDE:
            return { ...state, aside: action.payload }
        case actions.SET_MINIMUM_PRICE:
            return { ...state, minimumPrice: action.payload }
        case actions.SET_MAXIMUM_PRICE:
            return { ...state, maximumPrice: action.payload }
        case actions.FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, loading: true }
        case actions.FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loading: false, items: action.payload }
        case actions.FETCH_ITEMS_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, loading: false, items: action.payload }
        case actions.SET_VALUE_SEARCHED:
            return { ...state, valueSearched: action.payload }
        case actions.FETCH_CURRENT_ITEM_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, loading: true }
        case actions.FETCH_CURRENT_ITEM_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loading: false, currentItem: action.payload, aside: false }
        case actions.FETCH_CURRENT_ITEM_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, loading: false, currentItem: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a research I have foud out the solution.

Basically my question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804796/cant-access-nested-object-properties-in-a-single-object-from-json-call-in-react).

In my case I just have to set `currentItem: null` in the initial state inside my reducer, and then inside my component `return` I check for `currentItem` not being `null`, if so, I just proceed rendering the entire component.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this:

```
{currentItem.rating["1"]}
```

because your object has "string" ordering

UPDATE:
Check this code. It's not completely yours, but I think it help you solve the problem.

```
<div id="details">raiting {Object.values(item.rating).join(",")} </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-field-j5j61?file=/src/MyComp.js

Comment: It's like if it hasn't fetched the object itself yet, but then with other keys it works. Weird...

Comment: maybe you need to put `{currentItem.rating}` inside the loop with separate <li>?

Comment: mmm.. I tried <ul>{currentItem.rating.map( itemRating=>
                    <li>{itemRating}</li>
                )}</ul> but it says 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'

Comment: const detailsStr = `details ${currentItem.name} ${currentItem.rating['1']}`
and then use that string in `return` block?

Comment: @c_thane, thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it returns 'Cannot read property '1' of undefined'...

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that if I console log 'currentItem', it logs 8 times, and only the last four contain the actual item. The first four return 'undefined'

Comment: @MirkoOricci no worries. In that case i guess the only recourse is to 
`return currentItem.rating && (...)` ?

Comment: unbelievable, I tried now {currentItem.rating && <div>{currentItem.rating[1]}</div>} and I get the exact same error 'Cannot read property '1' of undefined', but it's just supposed to skip this block of code if it can't find currentItem.rating. I don't know what's going on here...

Comment: @MirkoOricci, maybe there is a reason check for the existence of the element `currentItem?` in your code? Like `<ul>{currentItem?.rating?.map( itemRating=> <li>{itemRating}</li> )}</ul>`

Comment: @Vova Wow, I've never seen this solution. Anyway it returns 'TypeError: _currentItem$rating.map is not a function'.

Comment: Maybe create your code here https://codesandbox.io/ ... and we can help you)

Comment: @Vova, I have used codesandbox before but only for small chucks of code. How does it work? do I have to recreate the whole project in there? How do I share it?

Comment: Also, I have tried {Object.entries(currentItem.rating)}, but I get '×
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'

Comment: @Vova, I think I got what you are trying to do :), I have used your code (only had to cange item to currentItem), but I still get 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'. Again, for some reason it doesn't seem to find the currentItem object from the state. What I don't get is why I am doing almost the same in another component and I have no problem...I ll keep working on it anyway, thanks